# Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%' Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am working with `Django` `Mezannine` and I am running into a weird issue with jinja.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /services/
Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.14/services/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in __init__, line 639
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.3
```

My code looks something like below:

```
{% for image in images %}
   {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %} #this is the line it doesn't like
     {{image}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

% is reserved by Django so you have to use divisibleby

```
{% for image in images %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
       {{image}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: "3" or 3? dont it need to be a number?

Comment: No, for Django 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby

Comment: Copy and pasted your line. New error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Got it figured out; its actually {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}

Comment: it's .counter not .index